# Splitting up an interval in weeks in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, split, range

Here goes a yet another SQL question about dates…

I'm building a calendaring application using PHP and Postgres that would display events spanning days, weeks or possibly months. Each event has a start date and an end date, and selecting them by range is not a problem; however, it would be useful for me if Postgres could split multi-week events at the first day of each week. I've been told it can be done using `GROUP BY` and `EXTRACT`, but I'm not good enough with SQL to understand how.

The question is: can this be done, and what would the precise query look like? Currently I'm using `SELECT * FROM events WHERE (range) OVERLAPS (range)`; and then doing the splitting in PHP, but it's clearly not optimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Postgres function [generate_series](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html). In 8.3 and earlier, do things like

```
select current_date + s.a as dates from generate_series(0,14,7) as s(a);
```

In 8.4, you can also do

```
SELECT * FROM generate_series('2008-03-01 00:00'::timestamp,
                              '2008-03-04 12:00', '10 hours');
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about `generate_series`. I'm currently using 8.3, so I guess I'll have to switch to 8.4 to really use the function, because applying the 8.3 example to dates seems a little difficult.

Comment: It's not that hard if you combine generate_series with an interval of '1 day'; there's a good example of doing that sort of thing on a monthly basis at http://www.mail-archive.com/pgsql-general@postgresql.org/msg134699.htmlbv

Answer (score 1):

First of all - it would be good to show some sample input and output of the query you'd like us to help you with - I, for example, don't really get what it is that you need.

Also - you might find OVERLAPS to be suboptimal, as it's not indexable. Instead you might want to use the method I described in [this blog post](http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2007/11/21/find-overlapping-time-ranges/).

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. This is an example of the results my query currently returns: <http://pastebin.com/d5021e30d>. The last two events span several months, and I'd like to split them into as many events as there are first days of the week inside that range. For example: <http://pastebin.com/d758bf244>.

Comment: Sorry, the URLs are broken. These are the correct ones:
* http://pastebin.com/d5021e30d
* http://pastebin.com/d758bf244